# How to plug in cosmos change feed processor in Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function in which the Startup class i hook custom configuration provider for Cosmos DB. But I would like to get the settings updated when a change happens in Cosmos DB. I know this can be achieved through Change feed processor. Is it possible to implement a watcher in my Azure Function to listen to changes and reload settings.  I am not asking how to hook an Azure Function for listening to change feed processor.

My implementation of IConfigurationSource is as below

```
    public class CosmosConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    private readonly string _carrierId;

    public CosmosConfigurationSource(string carrierId) =>
        _carrierId = carrierId;

    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) =>
        new CosmosConfigurationProvider(_carrierId);
}
```

and ConfigurationProvider

```
public class CosmosConfigurationProvider: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationProvider
{
    private ContainerWrapper _containerWrapper;
    private Container _container;
    private CosmosClient _cosmosClient;
    private readonly string _carrierId;

    public CosmosConfigurationProvider(string carrierId)
    {
        _carrierId = carrierId;
        init();
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        var settings = SearchByDocumentTypeWithPartitionKey(_carrierId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Data = settings.AsDictionary();
    }

    private void init()
    {
     /* not relevant here */
    }
    private async Task<SettingsModel> SearchByDocumentTypeWithPartitionKey(string carrierId)
    {
       /* not relevant here*/
    }
}
```

And in my Startup : FunctionsStartup

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Add(new CosmosConfigurationSource("405"));
    }
```

To plug the custom configuration provider. Loading the settings is working correctly.

When any of this settings present in the cosmos db changes I want them  to be available or even  to know that settings are changed, in my Azure Function, so that i can do a refresh of my settings.

Comment: Not enough information to go on here. Please show what this custom configuration provider looks like with code. What settings are you trying to update? Listen to what changes in Azure Functions?

Comment: Have you check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-functions ?

Comment: @Thomas i am not talking about an Azure Function which gets triggered with change feed

Comment: @MarkBrown i edited my question, hope it gives you enough information

Comment: Ho ok, you could always have an endpoint in your function listening on changefeed that will update the configuration when something has changed

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're doing. I don't see any code related to change feed. Change Feed is used to listen for changes to the data you are storing in a container. I'm not sure what this configuration extensions class is but it has nothing to do with Cosmos DB or change feed. For more information on change feed and what it does see,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed?toc=%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2Fsql%2Ftoc.json#working-with-change-feed

Comment: @MarkBrown i have not listed the code for change feed, it is not yet implemented and thats the question. The link you shared is known to me and i have implemented in other scenarios. The question is in the context of Custom configuration provider

Comment: What is it exactly you want to use change feed to listen to? Still not clear on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to

[Change feed processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor?tabs=dotnet)
I added the below methods in the Custom Configuration Provider

```
        private async Task<ChangeFeedProcessor> StartChangeFeedProcessorAsync(string databaseName, string leaseContainerName, string sourceContainerName)
    {
        Container leaseContainer = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, leaseContainerName);
        ChangeFeedProcessor changeFeedProcessor = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, sourceContainerName)
            .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<T2>(processorName: "changeFeedSample", onChangesDelegate: HandleChangesAsync)
            .WithInstanceName("consoleHost")
            .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
            .Build();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Change Feed Processor...");
        await changeFeedProcessor.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Change Feed Processor started.");
        return changeFeedProcessor;
    }

    async Task HandleChangesAsync(ChangeFeedProcessorContext context,
        IReadOnlyCollection<T2> changes,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.Load();
    }
```

and in the Custom Configuration Provider Constructor, start the change feed processor

```
StartChangeFeedProcessorAsync(databaseName, leaseContainerName, sourceContainerName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This reloaded the settings on CosmosDB document change.